# Down Casting in Java

Tags: java, casting, downcast

Can anyone here please explain to me why I get a java.lang.ClassCastException when downcasting a Parent to a Child?

```
public class Child extends Parent{
public static void main(String[] args){
    new Child().go();
}
void go(){
    go2(new Parent(), new Child());
    go2((Child) new Parent(), new Child());
}
void go2(Parent p1, Child c1){
    Child c2 = (Child)p1;
    Parent p2 = (Parent)c1;
} 
}
class Tree{}
```

I have read reference variable casting and searched for examples in the web. Can someone please explain it to me? I really want to understand why it throw exception. Thanks

Comment: you casting parent which is not child to child

Comment: It fails the IS-A test: a Child IS-A Parent, but a Parent is not a Child.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because of polymorphic reference, when you store a `sub-type` object to `super-type` reference, you can't use method specific to `sub-type`. but you can just get which are methods defined in `super-type`.

to be able to use sub-type methods, you need to cast the reference of `super-type` to `sub-type`.

```
Parent p = new Child();
...
...
((Child)p).childMethod();
```

but this is only possible when you know object assigned to `p` is actually of type `Child`. else it will give `ClassCastException`

Answer (score 3):

Lets say you Parent class Animal, and Child class Bird.
You can cast from Bird to Animal, because all Birds are Animals.
You CANNOT cast from Animal to Bird, because not all Animals are Birds.

Comment: then how can i apply downcasting for parent?

Comment: Parent is "lower" than child. So it would be "UPcast". And "upcasts" are impossible. Maybe you can tell me more, why you need that cast, and what exactly are you trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

Here is your problematic Code stripped:

```
go2(new Parent());

...

void go2(Parent p1){
    Child c2 = (Child)p1;
}
```

The compiler allows your cast of p1 from 'Parent' to 'Child' because p1 **could** be a 'Child'. You can however obviously see, that p1 is NOT a child. So your code is fine at compile time, but will crash at runtime.

That means, all added behaviour which you may have defined in your 'Child' class is not available since you only have an instance of Type 'Parent'.

Comment: I thought if a child extends a parent the parent can be downcasted to child? how can the downcasting be applied then? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> You can cast a `Child` to a `Parent`. Since `Child` extends `Parent`,
>   any instance of a `Child` is a `Parent` (but with extra stuff only
>   available to a `Child`). However, `p1` is a `Parent`. Since a `Parent`
>   is not a `Child`, you can't cast an instance of a `Parent` to a
>   `Child`.

I copied exactly the answer to a similar question form a [google search](https://www.google.hu/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=java%20downcasting%20classcastexception&oq=&gs_l=&pbx=1&fp=66447f4ba2242c6f&ion=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.46226182,d.bGE&biw=1920&bih=993). Please do your homework next time and read the FAQ.

Comment: thanks Adam. I have read the FAQ before I ask this question, I just want somebody to explain it to me because I am having trouble understanding downcasting.

Answer (score 0):

A `Parent` is not a `Child`. That is, a `Parent` does have the necessary fields to be treated as though it were an instance of `Child` and fulfill all the `Child` specific methods - the contract of `Child`. Imagine if `Child` had a variable `childOnly` and a method `childProcess` and you tried to call `childProcess` on an object that is a `Parent` in memory. It could not possibly work, so Java prevents you from treating Parents as Childs.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say `Car` is a bare-bone interface

```
Merc is a Car (Merc extends Car)

BMW  is a Car (BMW extends Car)
```

now

you can take  BMW and *treat* it bare-bone car as BMW as all the features of a Car. so you can Cast BMW to a Car   so `(Car car = (Car)bmw)` **is legal**.

If you take a bare-bone car and try to treat it as BMW, it cannot be done as BMW will have a lot more than a bare-bone car.

so,

`BMW bmw = (BMW)car` **is illegal**

The same real world concept is extended to Object Oriented world.